# How to show newly data added?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I want to ask why the newly added data does not display in the template, but it does show the newly added data in using `console.log` (see the **ViewPost.vue**).

This is the result after I add new post: [result.png](https://ibb.co/DCqLbCf). Someone knows how to achieve this?

---

Here is my parent component:

```
<template>
    <section>
        //more codes here
        <ViewPost v-for="data in postData" :key="data.post_id" :data="data" />
    </section>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex';
export default {
    components: {ViewPost},
    computed: {
        ...mapState({
            postData: state => state.post.datas,
        }),
    }
    //more codes here
};
</script>
```

And below is the **ViewPost.vue**

```
<template>
    <span>
        <div class="card mb-10">
            <h1>body</h1> 
            {{ data.post_body }}
        </div>
    </span>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        data: {},
    },
    
    created() {
        console.log(this.data);
    },
};
```

Comment: can you also share your console.log output ?

Comment: try to move `v-for` into `ViewPost.vue`, it must respond to changes of the whole array

Comment: @omerS here it is https://ibb.co/9yw68Zf

Comment: @Mik I won't do that Sir, my **ViewPost** is intended for single post viewing only

Comment: so it is coming to console log but not in the template am i right ?

Comment: @JuanCervantes ok, I see, seems you must define `data.post_body` before using or just pass `post_body` as a `prop`

Comment: @omerS After I create new data the console log displays it but it does not show in the **ViewPost** template, take note the console log is also in the **ViewPost**'s `created()` function

Comment: can you try  to write in your props in your data type: Object, required: true

Comment: your post id must be different for rerendering the components with `v-for`

Comment: @tuhin47 here's interesting Sir, I used vuejs devtools, yeah ur right the new post added has no key, but I'm confused why in it's `props` it has `post_id`. See the image https://ibb.co/qjDfgzP . I'm using `post_id` as my `key` for `v-for`

Comment: probably you mismatch the `id` and `post_id` when you pushed new element to the array.

Comment: you can simply try key as `:key="postData.length"`

Comment: @tuhin47 I don't get it, mismatch Sir. When I reload, all existing datas were rendered by the template properly using `post_id` as `key`. I did not use `id` as `key`. I just wondered why it can't pickup the newly added data's `post_id`.

Comment: @tuhin47 that resulted an error for duplication. **[Vue warn]: Duplicate keys detected: '12'**

Comment: I add an answer please check with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`index` as a key may work fine.

```
<template>
    <section>
        //more codes here
        <ViewPost v-for="(data,index) in postData" :key="index" :data="data" />
    </section>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex';
export default {
    components: {ViewPost},
    computed: {
        ...mapState({
            postData: state => state.post.datas,
        }),
    }
    //more codes here
};
</script>
```

**ViewPost.vue**

```
<template>
    <span>
        <div class="card mb-10">
            <h1>body</h1> 
            {{ data.post_body || data.body }}
        </div>
    </span>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['data']
    
    created() {
        console.log(this.data);
    },
};
```

Comment: I just tested Sir but all same, it did not render in the template but the `props` has it its. See the vuejs devtools result https://ibb.co/qCLD1jz

Comment: and bdw Sir I'm using `unshift`, I did not use `push` would these make a difference?

Comment: it work Sir. I now understand the problem, the newly added data was returning different from my fetch datas. heck thank you very much for your time sir. I upvoted

Comment: actually, you occur problem with the newly added data. You don't build the new data object as previous data. You changes the parameter names. Suppose, your already loaded data has the property name 'post_body'. but when you insert new one you set the property name just 'body'. This occurs problem